# Set property value from database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, resharper

I'm trying to set property values straight from database so i could initiate new object
`Object AllValues = new Object();` and access it in code like this `AllValues.MediumRunTime;`
using Entity Framework and it's returning 0's which it should't.
Also ReSharper is throwing `Field value is never assigned` warning

My table is `Values{name, value, units}` and contains around ~100 records.

This is my AllValues class

```
using System.Linq;

namespace RunTimes
{
    public class AllValues
    {
      private long value;
        public long ShortRunTime
        {
            get => value;
            set
            {
                using (var data = new ModelData())
                {
                    var prop = data.Values.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "ShortRunTime");
                    value = prop.value;
                }
            }
        }

        public long MediumRunTime
        {
            get => value;
            set
            {
                using (var data = new ModelData())
                {
                    var prop = data.Values.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "MediumRunTime");
                    value = prop.value;
                }
            }
        } 
...
```

And im trying to access it on Program.cs like this

```
AllValues av = new AllValues();
Console.WriteLine($"Medium run time: {av.MediumRunTime}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property setter is not the place to 'set a field with the value from the database', you use it to set the value of the property after you first loaded it from the database.

So instead of your AllValues class as it currently stands, you would have a class with some simple properties, such as:

```
class AllValues
{
    public string ShortRunTime { get; set; }
    public string MediumRunTime { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

and then instantiate it like this:

```
var av = new AllValues();

using (var data = new ModelData())
{
    av.ShortRunTime = data.Values.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "ShortRunTime")?.Value;
    av.MediumRunTime = data.Values.FirstOrDefault(c => c.name == "MediumRunTime")?.Value;
     // ...
}
```

After this you can work with your class in memory. The 'trick' is to separate concerns: your 'transformed class' (`AllValues`) and loading data from the database are 2 different concerns that should be treated separately.

Comment: I had pretty similar code to this before, but was wondering if it's possible to "to do it all at once", guess not. Will do it like this. Thanks.

Comment: Well there are probably ways to do it more efficiently. Since you're mapping string values from the database to property names, you could load all values in a dictionary and pass that as a field to your AllValues object. Or maybe use some reflection.